# metal encoder dispatch based on value of an atomic counter

Tags: gpgpu, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to find a way to reduce synchronization time between two kernel calls, where one dispatch depends on an atomic counter from the other.

Example: If I have two metal kernels, `select` and `execute`, `select` is looking through the `numbers`-buffer and stores the index of all numbers `< 10` in a new buffer `selectedNumberIndices` by using an atomic counter. `execute` is then run `counter` number of times do do something with those selected indices.

```
kernel void select (device atomic_uint &counter,
                    device uint *numbers,
                    device uint *selectedNumberIndices,
                    uint id [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    if(numbers[id] < 10) {
        uint idx = atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&counter, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
        selectedNumbers[idx] = id;
    }
}

kernel void execute (device uint *selectedNumberIndices,
                     uint id [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    // do something #counter number of times
}
```

currently I can do this by using `.waitUntilCompleted()` between the dispatches to ensure I get accurate results, something like:

```
// select
buffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer()!
encoder = buffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!
encoder.setComputePipelineState(selectState)
encoder.setBuffer(counterBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
encoder.setBuffer(numbersBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
encoder.setBuffer(selectedNumberIndicesBuffer, index: 2)
encoder.dispatchThreads(.init(width: Int(numbersCount), height: 1, depth: 1),
                        threadsPerThreadgroup: .init(width: selectState.threadExecutionWidth, height: 1, depth: 1))
encoder.endEncoding()
buffer.commit()

// wait
buffer.waitUntilCompleted()

// execute
buffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer()!
encoder = buffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!
encoder.setComputePipelineState(executeState)
encoder.setBuffer(selectedNumberIndicesBuffer, index: 0)
var counterValue: uint = 0 // extract the value of the atomic counter
counterBuffer.contents().copyBytes(to: &counterValue, count: MemoryLayout<UInt32>.stride)
encoder.dispatchThreads(.init(width: Int(counterValue), height: 1, depth: 1),
                        threadsPerThreadgroup: .init(width: executeState.threadExecutionWidth, height: 1, depth: 1))
encoder.endEncoding()
buffer.commit()
```

My question is if there is any way I can have this same functionality without the costly `buffer.waitUntilCompleted()` call? Or am I going about this in completely the wrong way, or missing something else?

Thankful for any pointers!

Comment: There's `dispatchThreadgroups(indirectBuffer:indirectBufferOffset:threadsPerThreadgroup:)` that you can use.

Comment: You can also use `MTLIndirectCommandBuffer`

Comment: @JustSomeGuy thanks for the comment! would you mind providing an example call for something like the example — or where I can learn about it? Maybe apple did apple a WWDC talk on it? Google results are sparse for examples.

Comment: Oh, I found an old answer of yours pointing to some resources!

Comment: dispatchThreadgroups(indirectBuffer:indirectBufferOffset:threadsPerThreadgroup:)

solved my issue, thank you!

@JustSomeGuy do you know why `threadsPerThreadgroup: executeState.threadExecutionWidth` literally freezes my computer if I use it with the indirectBuffer dispatch? (using MTLSize(1,1,1) works fine); `executeState.threadExecutionWidth` works well if I dispatch normally.

Comment: You mean using `MTLSize(executeState.threadExecutionWidth,1,1)` as a size? If I had to guess, it launches threads that read garbage, which leads to a GPU hang, which might hinder WindowServer, which might look like computer froze.

Comment: I suggest verifying workload with shader validation enabled. It will point out out some of the undefined behaviors that might lead to GPU restarts